# Hosting multiple WCF services at same time - they share Service name

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost

I have a WCF services library project in which I have 2 classes with the [ServiceContract] attribute.

I have a console application which is going to host the 2 services.

Code:

```
Uri baseAddressRetrieve = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/api/Retrieve/");
Uri baseAddressStorage = new Uri("http://localhost:8005/api/Storage/");

ServiceHost hostRetrieve = new ServiceHost(typeof(Retrieve), baseAddressRetrieve);
ServiceHost hostStorage = new ServiceHost(typeof(Storage), baseAddressStorage);

hostRetrieve.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRetrieve), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "Retrieve");
hostStorage.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStorage), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "Storage");

hostRetrieve.Open();
hostStorage.Open();
```

Now when I access both service addresses via URI they are both labelled "Storage Service" and in the code generated both have this line of code:

```
StorageClient client = new StorageClient();
```

Surely the Retrieve service should be RetrieveClient ?

`app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="NS.Retrieve">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NS.IRetrieve">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/NS/Retrieve/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="NS.Storage">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NS.IStorage">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/NS/Storage/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If it's WCF, it's a configuration problem. Please post your entire web.config (server and client).

Comment: app.config: http://pastebin.com/qSsA7zS8